# silent notification to alert in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending a silent notification to a user that gets picked up trough "didReceiveRemoteNotification fetchCompletionHsndler"  where I want to check som conditions and if it returns "true" for thoese want to make notificaton visible to a user -any idea on how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are 2 ways for that.

If your condition returns true then:

1) Your app is an **active state** then use any third party/alert to show that navigation content.

2) Your app is in the **background** then fire local notification with exact content of the silent notification.

like this:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:1]; // will fire notification after 1 second
notification.alertBody = @""; // pass your body text here
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Comment: may I ask how to fire local notification from that methode? (not me that gave U minus":) )

Comment: @pb4now Updated the answer please check